# Tcp в linux, программирование на с++

Tags: tcp, сокет, c++, linux

Есть проблема:
Программа работает с большим количеством клиентов и выделяет большое количество портов. Для каждого клиента выделяется один порт. Как узнать какие порты свободны, а какие нет. Программа многопоточная.

Comment: Я уже у Вас спрашивал в Вашем вопросе http://hashcode.ru/questions/213986/c-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2 , что же это должно из себя представлять. Ответа -- увы, нет. А на этот вопрос --- могу только присоединиться к @KoVadiv -- "плохая идея".

Comment: Странная идея. 

Нужно же еще каким-то образом сообщать клиенту, что для него выделен такой-то порт...

Чем обычный метод - один порт для всех - не устраивает?

Comment: @avp Было чего-то, не помню, какой-то чат. Когда пользователь авторизовался на сервере, затем толи сервер, толи визави устанавливал соединение с этим клиентом, причём на разные порты из диапазона (головняк по настройке файрвола, учитывая, что в организации к входящим соединениям относились без симпатии)

Comment: @alexlz, так ведь у Вас ***клиент*** *"открывал" новый порт*, а сервер-то слушал один и тот же (по которому шла авторизация).

Comment: @avp Не у меня, поэтому и пишу так неуверенно. Авторизовался клиент соответственно по одному порту, затем получал номер порт, который слушал. Кажется. (информация по обрывкам разговоров надцатилетней давности)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подобный подход в корне не верен. Необходимо идти от резервирования. Администратор сервера в настройках указывает сами порты, перечисляя их или указывая диапазон.

Например,
Ports = 4560, 4480, 8560
Ports = 4560-5580

Сервис же должен работать в пределах указанного диапазона.

Почему так лучше?
На сервере могут быть установлены другие сервисы. В случае безконтрольного захвата портов не исключены конфликтные ситуации, которые решить никак не удастся.

Answer (score 2):

плохая это идея - узнавать, какие порты открытые. Это не даст ничего. Если программа многопоточная, то порты могут постоянно выделятся новые, старые закрываться.

Скорее всего Вам просто нужно создать сокет на свободном порту. Для этого при вызове listen задается 0 порт. Система автоматически найдет доступный порт и выделит его. А какое именно у него значение - это можно узнать позже с помощью getsockname.

Answer (score 0):

```
ClientSocket1->Port = твое значение;
ClientSocket2->Port = твое значение;
ClientSocket3->Port = твое значение;
.
.
.
ClientSocketN->Port = твое значение;
```

Далее проверка активности порта:

```
if (ClientSocket1->Active == true) {
[...ЧТО ТЕБЕ НУЖНО...]
}
```

Comment: Круто! А поподробней можно?

Comment: может все таки массив, а не несколько переменных?
А так, по факту, это просто пул подключений.

Comment: Можно и массив. А вопрос в чем? Работа с WinSocket.

Comment: ага, в линукс и с WinSocket.

Comment: Вопрос прочитал а заголовок нет!)

Comment: Проблема была решена с помошью стека портов, которые можно использовать и словаря с занятыми портами и Pid процесса потомка, который работает с этим портом. После завершения работы порт удалялся из словаря и возвращался в стек. Таким образом получается что работают лишь необходимые порты и ничего лишнего.